# Fade in leaflet markers when added

Tags: css, leaflet

My map loads icons from the API while scrolling around.  The delay makes the markers pop into existence, which I don't like visually.  Preferably, they would grow from a pixel to their normal size or fade in.  I figured fade in wouldn't be too hard to do with css3 transitions.  Markers have the method `setOpacity(n)` so I tried initializing the marker like

```
@marker = L.marker(
    coordinates,
    {opacity: .1}
).on('add', ->
    @setOpacity(1)
)
```

because I realized adding a marker was async so if I set the opacity too early, the transition wouldn't apply because the marker element wasn't in the DOM and the marker would render at full opacity.  This is why I tried listening to the `add` event.  But that doesn't work.  apparently the event fires too early.  If i put setOpacity in a timeout, it works fine.  But I do not think that is a good way to write this, especially because it introduces even more delay on top of the API.

How can I fade in my icons?  I think a lot of people want this feature, so maybe it would be a good leaflet plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done by attaching a keyframe animation to the leaflet-marker-icon and leaflet-marker-shadow classes. The keyframe animation is what does the trick because it's selfinvoking, so you don't need to add any classes at runtime to start the animation. Animation works when the map is loaded with markers and when markers are added. Try the example below the code:

```
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 3s; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

An example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kw4zFqqbtfEFQzN4fg8U?p=preview

Comment: I saw that but I was under the impression that it controls how markers move when changing the zoom level of the map.  Does it actually control how they appear when created?  From the documentation: Whether markers animate their zoom with the zoom animation, if disabled they will disappear for the length of the animation. By default it's enabled in all browsers that support CSS3 Transitions except Android.

Comment: I'm sorry, i was wrong because i misinterpreted your question. One thing was correct, this can simply be done by using CSS. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: AHAH!  I didn't know there was a css animation for that.  A much better fit than using opacity.  Thank you very much!